# Unexpected exception for remote running unit tests with MethodHandles

Tags: java, maven, reflection

The following line of code in tests

```
var lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
```

where Field is java.lang.reflect.Field
throws a

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not open java.lang.reflect to unnamed module @497470ed
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(MethodHandles.java:260) ~[?:?]
```

The code works fine if tests are run locally (either via IDE or maven lifecycle), but fails on maven test run on CI pipeline on a remote host.

Maven is configured for java 11, but test execution as we saw in logs was using openjdk-16 jvm.

Would appreciate any ideas on where to look.

Comment: Java 16 changed the default value of `--illegal-access`  to `deny`. See [JEP 403](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, what would be the most proper fix/workaround in this case?

Comment: Don't do such things?

Comment: I really like the sentence “*This means that all internal elements of the JDK will be strongly encapsulated except for critical internal APIs such as sun.misc.Unsafe.*” which means, we finally make this house secure, but as always, not forget to put the master key under the doormat.